# All Variables in Playbook Except ansible_*

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I would like to display the variables being used in my playbook. The variable `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` has all the information I want, but about 70% of the variables start with 'ansible_', which I would like to filter out.

I suspect I can use a filter such as

```yaml
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | rejectattr('ansible[*]', 'defined') }}
```

but I'm not finding the correct format that gives me the output I want. Most of the filters operate on the attributes of a variable as opposed to the variable name itself. I suspect I can use `| to_json` but I'm still having difficulty manipulating the output.

1. Is there an alternate variable group I can use other than `hostvars` that doesn't require filtering?
2. If a filter is the way to go, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an alternate variable group I can use other than hostvars that doesn't require filtering?

No. `hostvars` is a list of variables set for this host, which includes facts set via the `setup` task as well as those you set explicitly using `set_fact`, `host_vars` files, etc.

> If a filter is the way to go, any suggestions?

You're on the right track! You can use the [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) to transform the dictionary into something that is more amendable to filtering with `rejectattr`, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]|dict2items|rejectattr("key", "match", "ansible")|items2dict
```

We're using the `match` test here, which matches regular expression anchored to the beginning of the string, so this will reject any keys that start with `ansible`.

Running that playbook on my system produces:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]|dict2items|rejectattr(\"key\", \"match\", \"ansible\")|items2dict": {
        "gather_subset": [
            "all"
        ],
        "group_names": [],
        "groups": {
            "all": [],
            "ungrouped": []
        },
        "inventory_hostname": "localhost",
        "inventory_hostname_short": "localhost",
        "module_setup": true,
        "omit": "__omit_place_holder__ef809c7b9cdf63b1506089085eb169c56682b5e3",
        "playbook_dir": "/home/lars/tmp/ansible"
    }
}
```